# How can be used phone locks as a action trigger in Swift?

Tags: swift, triggers, viewcontroller

I want to change to another viewcontroller in swift when the phone is locked. Is there any variable or function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user locks their phone 'applicationWillResignActive' and then 'applicationDidEnterBackground' from the App Delegate get called and then when the user unlock it - 'applicationWillEnterForeground' and 'applicationDidBecomeActive' get called. You can either implement your view controller to be pushed in the App Delegate or add a notification observer in your view controller to react to any of these and push/pop/modally present the view controller you need. It all depends on your implementation - it is a bit of a broad question. Hope this helps!